# How to increase the width of this date range selector textbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Click here to view Image of mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc8EL.jpg)Hi I want to increase the width of the date range selector text box.[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eovxs.jpg)

Coding below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <label> Date Range</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="daterange" data-GetData="week" data-daterangepickerid="1" id="daterangepicker" class="date-range-picker" value="01/05/2017 - 01/06/2017" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <label>Id </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NRIC, new { @class = "form-control", id = "NRIC" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I want date range text box width same as text box width.. How to increase??

Comment: have you tried to add a width to the **.date-range-picker** class? ( ex: `width:60%;` )

Comment: just now I tried as per first comment

Comment: try with a `max-width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the style property of the input

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" style="width: 300px" data-GetData="week" data-daterangepickerid="1" id="daterangepicker" class="date-range-picker" value="01/05/2017 - 01/06/2017" />
<!-------------- the width you need --------------^^^^^---->
```

or add a new CSS rule

```
input[name=daterange]{
    width: 300px;
}
```

you have to adjust the width to whatever you need ... :D

---

Update:
use a container with `min-width` and `max-width` css rules

```
<div style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 50%">
    <input type="text" name="daterange" style="width: 100%" data-GetData="week" data-daterangepickerid="1" id="daterangepicker" class="date-range-picker" value="01/05/2017 - 01/06/2017" />
</div>
```

Comment: hi ur one is working , but how to adjust when  the size is in mobile sixe.. When I change to mobile size, it overlaps..

Comment: then you better create a container with prozentual width and height and set the width to `100%`.

Comment: I added my image in question

Comment: How to create that container

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using row and column, you could just set the width to 100%. Add padding/margin if needed. Example CSS:

```
.date-range-picker {
    width: 100%;
}
```